# How to collect coverage of image onload?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, code-coverage, jestjs, drawimage

I'm using React to draw a canvas with images drawed by drawImage.
Everything works ok but I can't collect the coverage of onload function when UT for it. Anyone have a solution?

```
componentDidMount() {
  const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = testImg;
  img.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
}
render() {
  return (
    <article>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A React.js Boilerplate application homepage" />
      </Helmet>
      <div>
        <Section>
          <canvas
            width="400px"
            height="400px"
            ref={(canvas) => this.canvas = canvas} // eslint-disable-line
            style={{ border: '1px solid #000000', marginTop: '20px' }}
          />
        </Section>
      </div>
    </article>
  );
}
```

And the coverage result

[image]

Comment: Can you show your react code?

Comment: I updated my code and the coverage result

Comment: Hi @QuangAnhPham. How did you solve the coverage for this approach?

Comment: What I do is just return the img at the end of the function and and call img.onload()